# botocore s3 put has issue hashing file due to encoding?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, botocore

I'm having trouble figuring out why the file, the contents of which are "DELETE ME LATER", which is loaded with encoding `utf-8` causes an exception in botocore when it's being hashed.

```
with io.open('deleteme','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  try:
    resp=client.put_object(
    Body=f,
    Bucket='s3-bucket-actual-name-for-real',
    Key='testing/a/put'
    )
    print('deleteme exists')
    print(resp)
  except:
    print('deleteme could not put')
    raise
```

Produces:

> deleteme could not put
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "./test_operator.py", line 41, in 
>       Key='testing/a/put'   File "/Users/lamblin/VEnvs/awscli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py",
>   line 312, in _api_call
>       return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/Users/lamblin/VEnvs/awscli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py",
>   line 582, in _make_api_call
>       request_signer=self._request_signer, context=request_context)   File
>   "/Users/lamblin/VEnvs/awscli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py",
>   line 242, in emit_until_response
>       responses = self._emit(event_name, kwargs, stop_on_response=True)   File
>   "/Users/lamblin/VEnvs/awscli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py",
>   line 210, in _emit
>       response = handler(**kwargs)   File "/Users/lamblin/VEnvs/awscli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py",
>   line 201, in conditionally_calculate_md5
>       calculate_md5(params, **kwargs)   File "/Users/lamblin/VEnvs/awscli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py",
>   line 179, in calculate_md5
>       binary_md5 = _calculate_md5_from_file(body)   File "/Users/lamblin/VEnvs/awscli/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py",
>   line 193, in _calculate_md5_from_file
>       md5.update(chunk)
>   TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Now this can be avoided by opening the file with 'rb' but, isn't the file object `f` clearly using an encoding?

Comment: Any good reason why you want to use `put_object` and not the higher-level api of `client.upload_fileobj`?

Comment: @wim the task will be pickled and queued up on a worker which only has botocore installed, not boto3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now this can be avoided by opening the file with 'rb' but, isn't the file object f clearly using an encoding?

The encoding specified to `io.open` in `mode='r'` is used to *decode* the content.  So when you iterate `f`, the content has already been converted from `bytes` to `str` (text) by Python.

To interface with `botocore` directly, open your file with mode `'rb'`, and drop the encoding `kwarg`.  There is no point to decode it to text when the first thing `botocore` will have to do in order to transport the content is just encode back into bytes again.